# Download a PDF from url, edit it an render it in Django

Tags: python, django, azure, pypdf

I need to download a PDF form Azure Storage, edit the file (extract an specific page) and render it from a Django view, I have this:

```
import urllib.request
import re
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter
import io

def download_desprendible_user(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        url = 'https://example.blob.core.windows.net/mypdf.pdf' # The url where I take the pdf file
        file = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
        id = 'foo' # Key word I want to find within the pdf to extract that page

        reader = PdfFileReader(io.BytesIO(file.read()))
        for i in range(0, reader.getNumPages()):
            content = ""
            content += reader.getPage(i).extractText() + "\n"
            ResSearch = re.search(id, content)
            if ResSearch is not None:
                page = i
                break
        
        pdfWriter = PdfFileWriter()
        pdfWriter.addPage(reader.getPage(page))

        with io.BytesIO() as out:
            pdfWriter.write(out)
```

But I can't achieve to render the pdf from the Django view, I don't want to use `open` because I had issue in production by doing this.

EDIT1:

This did work for me but NOT in production:

```
import urllib.request
import re
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter
import io

def download_desprendible_user(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        url = 'https://example.blob.core.windows.net/mypdf.pdf' # The url where I take the pdf file
        file = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
        id = 'foo' # Key word I want to find within the pdf to extract that page

        reader = PdfFileReader(io.BytesIO(file.read()))
        for i in range(0, reader.getNumPages()):
            content = ""
            content += reader.getPage(i).extractText() + "\n"
            ResSearch = re.search(id, content)
            if ResSearch is not None:
                page = i
                break
        
        pdfWriter = PdfFileWriter()
        pdfWriter.addPage(reader.getPage(page))

        with open('media/test.pdf', 'wb') as f:
            pdfWriter.write(f)
            f.close()

        return FileResponse(open('media/test.pdf', 'rb'), content_type='application/pdf')
```

EDIT2:

This works but had to change the /media path for another one, not sure if is the best solution yet:

```
import urllib.request
import re
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter
import io

def download_desprendible_user(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        url = 'https://example.blob.core.windows.net/mypdf.pdf' # The url where I take the pdf file
        file = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
        id = 'foo' # Key word I want to find within the pdf to extract that page

        reader = PdfFileReader(io.BytesIO(file.read()))
        for i in range(0, reader.getNumPages()):
            content = ""
            content += reader.getPage(i).extractText() + "\n"
            ResSearch = re.search(id, content)
            if ResSearch is not None:
                page = i
                break
        
        pdfWriter = PdfFileWriter()
        pdfWriter.addPage(reader.getPage(page))

        with open('test/test.pdf', 'wb') as f:
            pdfWriter.write(f)
            f.close()

        return FileResponse(open('test/test.pdf', 'rb'), content_type='application/pdf')
```

Comment: this is not a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example, also where does the `id` value come from?

Comment: Thanks, I'm fairly new using stackoverflow, let me try to improve the code, id is the key word I'm trying to find within the pdf page

Comment: No worries, also for `id` https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id gives the memory address so the code isn't doing what you want. Change that to `'id'` (with quotes) which will turn it into a string. also keep in mind that `re.search` will return the first instance of the string, which might be before the page you are looking to render.

Comment: add the `import` statements for the packages that are being used too, e.g. where does `PdfFileReader` come from?

Comment: Good, the re.search part should not be a problem as I'm expecting the word to be only once within the file, but get the point

Comment: there is no call to `render` in the function, so you need to include one. E.g. `render(request, context={'content': content})` but this requires placing in the correct scope inside the function. You also need a `from django.shortcuts import render` to access the render function.

Comment: so is your question how to render the string `content` client side?

Comment: Yes, that's the part I'm struggling with, I can't get a way for the user to download the file without having to open the file (ie. using  with open(pdf_path, 'rb') as f:). That did work for me in in development, but not in production

Comment: actually, I'm still not clear on what you're trying to achieve, are you trying to serve the pdf file directly to the client (as a pdf), or serve the text of the pdf to the client in an html format?

Comment: Yes, what I'm trying to do is to serve the pdf (that unique page that I extracted) in .pdf format to the cliente

Comment: does this not work for you? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/outputting-pdf/#write-your-view it says `accepts any file-like object with binary content` so the `BytesIO` should work as an argument. What is the error you get if you try that?

Comment: I got this error AttributeError: asUnicode(<_io.BytesIO object at 0x00000215653EC860>,enc='utf8') error:  '_io.BytesIO' object has no attribute 'decode'

Comment: it's more helpful if you can paste the code you're executing and what the error message is

Comment: I partially found a solution, I used the code shown in EDIT 1 above but just changed the /media path for a new one. I don't think is the best solution but works for now, thank you very much for your help Lucas, if you think of a better solution I'll be happy to try it